# Combine multiple table schemas in one separate table in databricks

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I am learning Databricks and going through an exploring and research phase. I found various tools while triaging python syntax. I.e. **Dataframes** with **PySpark**, **Bamboo** library, **Apache Spark** library to read SQL objects, Panda etc.

But somehow I am mixing up the usage of these all libraries.

I am exploring these alternatives to achieve one task. How to combine or merge multiple table schemas in one table.

For an instance, if I have 20 tables. Table1, Table2, Table3, ... , Table20.

### Table1 has 3 columns.

Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |

### Table2 has 4 columns.

Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7

and that way all 20 table has such columns.

Can the community provide some insight to approach this implementation?

This is greatly appreciated.

**Troubleshooting**

```
schema1 = "database string, table string"
schema2 = "table string, column string, datatype string"

tbl_df = spark.createDataFrame([],schema1)
tbl_df3 = spark.createDataFrame([],schema2)

db_list = [x[0] for x in spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES").rdd.collect()]

for db in db_list:
   # Get list of tables from each the database
   db_tables = spark.sql(f"SHOW TABLES in {db}").rdd.map(lambda row: row.tableName).collect()

   # For each table, get list of columns
    for table in db_tables:
        #initialize the database
        spark.sql(f"use {db}")
    
        df = spark.createDataFrame([(db, table.strip())], schema=['database', 'table'])
        tbl_df = tbl_df.union(df)
```

above code works fine and gives me list of all databases and tables associated. Now next thing I am trying to achieve is `schema2`.
Based on list of tables, I managed to retrieve list of columns from all tables. But I believe it returns in the form of `tuple`.
For example, when I iterate for loop on `db_tables` as below,

```
columns = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE TABLE {table}").rdd.collect()
```

this gives me below result.

```
[Row(col_name='Col1', data_type='timestamp', comment=None), Row(col_name='Col2', data_type='string', comment=None), Row(col_name='Col3', data_type='string', comment=None)]

[Row(col_name='Col4', data_type='timestamp', comment=None), Row(col_name='Col5', data_type='timestamp', comment=None), Row(col_name='Col6', data_type='timestamp', comment=None), Row(col_name='Col7', data_type='timestamp', comment=None)]
```

This is my real challenge now. I try to figure out to access above `Row` format and transform in below tabular outcome.

```
Table | Column | Datatype
-------------------------
Table1|  Col1   | Timestamp
Table1|  Col2   | string
Table1|  Col3   | string
Table2|  Col4   | Timestamp
Table2|  Col5   | string
Table2|  Col6   | string
Table2|  Col7   | string
```

Finally I will merge or join 2 dataframes based on table name (taking it as key) and generate final outcome like below.

```
Database| Table | Column | Datatype
------------------------------------
Db1     | Table1|  Col1   | Timestamp
Db1     | Table1|  Col2   | string
Db1     | Table1|  Col3   | string
Db1     | Table2|  Col4   | Timestamp
Db1     | Table2|  Col5   | string
Db1     | Table2|  Col6   | string
Db1     | Table2|  Col7   | string
```

Comment: Is there any common identity column present in the data your tables?

Comment: Thanks for response @SaideepArikontham. Based on your script and some brainstroming at my end I managed to finalize what type of outcome is required. The format of final outcome should be a tabular structure

Database | Table | Column | Datatype 

Let me write my triage in my question. I managed to get the list of database and tables associated in one dataframe. Next task is to bring list of columns (names, datatypes) in another dataframe and then merge 2 dataframes in one and create a consolidated table as final outcome.

Comment: Hey @Binoy, I have updated the solution. Check if it is the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each table has unique columns, you can use `unionByName`.To create a single table with merged schema, you can use the following code:

```
#list of table names
tables = ['default.t1','default.t2','default.t3']

final_df = spark.sql(f'select * from {tables[0]}') #load 1st table to a dataframe
#display(final_df)

final = 'final_df'
for table in tables[1:]:
    final = final + f'.unionByName(spark.sql("select * from {table}"),allowMissingColumns=True)'  #creating string expression to get final result
#print(final)

req_df = eval(final)
#display(req_df)
req_df.printSchema()
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

To get the database name, table name, column name and their type for each of the table in each of the database, you can use the following code:

- My table creation code:

```
%sql
create database d1;
create table d1.t1(id int, gname varchar(40));
create table d1.t2(fname varchar(40),lname varchar(40));
create database d2;
create table d2.tb1(id varchar(40),age int, name varchar(40));
```

- To get dataframe as per requirement:

```
db_list = [x[0] for x in spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES").rdd.collect()]
#db_list

db_tables = spark.sql(f"SHOW TABLES in {db_list[0]}")
for i in db_list[1:]:
    db_tables = db_tables.union(spark.sql(f"SHOW TABLES in {i}"))
#display(db_tables)
```

[image]

```
final_df = None
for row in db_tables.collect():
    if(final_df is None):
        final_df = spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE TABLE {row.database}.{row.tableName}")\
        .withColumn('database',lit(f'{row.database}'))\
        .withColumn('tablename',lit(f'{row.tableName}'))\
        .select('database','tablename','col_name','data_type')
    else:
        final_df = final_df.union(spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE TABLE {row.database}.{row.tableName}")\
        .withColumn('database',lit(f'{row.database}'))\
        .withColumn('tablename',lit(f'{row.tableName}'))\
        .select('database','tablename','col_name','data_type'))
display(final_df)
```

[image]

Comment: Simple and concise. This has increased my interest in learning python and data science as career path. Please share if there are useful resources for that.